# how can i make an axios request to my local server

Tags: javascript, axios

This is the code, the code is ran when the input field is filled and submitted by clicking the submit button, I am getting the error below

```
async function axiosInAction() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("localhost:1337/firstc/list", {
      //my params as an object
      name: signUpDetails
    });
    console.log("this isthe response" + " " + response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
axiosInAction();
```

Error:

> Failed to load localhost:1337/firstc/list: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://` before `localhost:1337`?

Comment: Can you post the `server.js ` where the api is actually serving ?